# how to limit Dovecot.index.cache size

Tags: cache, dovecot

In my server I have various email accounts having a very large
dovecot.index.cache file

i.e.

> -rw-r-----   1 user user 72506540 Sep 16 20:20 dovecot.index.cache

is there any way to size limit dovecot.index files, especially 
dovecot.index.cache ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can simply delete index file by hand and dovecot recreate it. If index size so big because of some fault, recreated one will be significantly smaller. If recreated index become the same size then this size is exact size it should be.

Index size is dependant on the size of mailbox and can be really large if Full-Text Search aka FTS is turned on.

Comment: I know it (I can delete indexes and Dovecot will recreate them), but I have over 1 thousand email and deleting the index files by hand is not a solution. I was thinking Dovecot developers thought a config to do this step automatically to avoid extra disk usage in the server. As it seems they didn't it.

Comment: Storage overhead is the small price we should pay to lower disk i/o that is the main bottleneck. Nowaday storage is cheap so developers make a reasonable decision.